# DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this exception when I am using Firebase in Digits by twitter. I am using digits from twitter. I found a solution, but nothing worked out for me till now. `

```
digitsButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
            // TODO: associate the session user ID with your user model

            firebaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(phoneNumber)) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).equals(phoneNumber)) {
                            firebaseReference.setValue(phoneNumber);
                            firebaseReference.removeEventListener(this);

                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));

                        } else {
                            firebaseReference.removeEventListener(this);
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
            Log.d("Digits", "Sign in with Digits failure", exception);
        }
    });
```

.

```
 Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/user/0/com.curieo.podcast.debug/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db, table = null, query = select count(1) from messages
                                                                android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:104)
                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:50)
                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1346)
                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1285)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatw.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatu.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatu.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatu$4.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzato$zzd.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have been stuck on this from hours and cannot understand how is it causing a problem

Comment: Have you been using sqlite? It seems the error has something to do with it.

Comment: This is a known bug in Google/Firebase code: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37128983.  See also: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/176

Comment: @BobSnyder How do I get around this. Cant uderstand what to do..??

Comment: You are seeing the logs because [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder.html) is configured to detect leaked closable objects. If the leak is crashing your app,  you must have selected `penaltyDeath()`.  Instead, select `penaltyLog()`, to see the logs but no exception, or disable detection of leaked objects.

Comment: I have selected `penaltyLog()` Even if there is a leaked cloasable object my code should run fine. But it's not going inside the `onDataChange()` function. @BobSnyder

Comment: Add a log statement to `onCancelled()` to see if security rules are blocking the read.

Comment: @BobSnyder Does'n't show any errors.